# setting up constraints in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have the following problem:

weights vector =[0.05,0.05,0.15, 0.05,0.22, 0.08, 0.4]

weights vector header =[A11 ,A12 , A21, A22, A31,A32,B1 ]  I have the following constraints

0≤A11+A12 + A21+ A22 + A31+A32 ≤0.3

0≤B1≤0.8

A11+A12 =A21+A22 =A31+A32

A11+A12 + A21+ A22 + A31+A32 + B1=1

I want to minimize sum of squared difference to the original weight vector subject to the above constraints

how do I specify this in quadprog in MATLAB the constraints?

Apologies for not formatting well, I am fairly new to stack overflow

Here is some sample basic code

```
weights.data = [0.05 0.05 0.15 0.05 0.22 0.08 0.4]
weights.header = {'A11', 'A12', 'A21', 'A22', 'A31', 'A32', 'B1'}
w0 = weights.data
Constraints = [
    1 0 1
    1 0 1
    1 0 1
    1 0 1
    1 0 1
    1 0 1
    0 1 1

    ]

ub = [0.3 0.8 1]
lb = [0 0 1]

A0 = Constraints;

%%Inequality constraints
A_le = [-A0, A0]'; % lower bound first
b_le = [-lb, ub];
n = 7

[solution, fval, exitflag,output] = quadProg(eye(n), -w0', A_le,b_le,[],[],[],[],w0, options);













Thanks for your help!
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to demonstrate the problem setup?  Also, readers would appreciate if you could do some [code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).